# getting latest data in one to many relation table

Tags: mysql

i would like to fetch data from table a,b,c but order by most recent data of table response

table casework has this structure ( simplified):

```
casework_id | problem   | user_id          
------------+-----------+-------
1           | Problem1  | 1  
2           | Problem2  | 2
3           | Problem3  | 1
4           | Problem4  | 3
```

table user has this structure ( simplified):

```
user_id | name         
--------+-----------------
1       | peter  
2       | Sam  
3       | Tom  
4       | Steve
```

table response has this structure ( simplified):

```
response_id | response   | casework_id | created           
------------+-----------+--------------+-------
1           | responce1  |  1      | 2012-10-14 11:28:31
2           | responce2  |  1      | 2012-9-10 11:28:31 
3           | responce3  |  1      | 2012-9-2 11:28:31
4           | responce4  |  3      | 2012-8-3 11:28:31
4           | responce5  |  3      | 2012-8-2 11:28:31
```

I am looking the query to fetch data order by latest responce and group by casework_id

```
I. e. required out put is 

casework_id | problem   | name  | responce  | created        
------------+-----------+-------+-----------+---------
1           | Problem1  | peter | responce1 | 2012-10-14 11:28:31
2           | Problem2  | Sam   | Null      | Null
3           | Problem3  | peter | responce4 | 2012-8-3 11:28:31 
4           | Problem4  | Tom   | Null      | Null
```

I would be most grateful if one of you kind people could point me in the right direction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the following:

```
select c.casework_id,
  c.problem,
  u.name,
  r2.response,
  r1.created
from casework c
left join user u
  on c.user_id = u.user_id
left join
(
  select max(created) created, casework_id
  from response r
  group by casework_id
) r1
  on c.casework_id = r1.casework_id
left join response r2
  on r1.created = r2.created
  and r1.casework_id = r2.casework_id
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/95692/10)

If you want to include both the user that created the casework and then who responsed, then you will want to join on the `user` table twice:

```
select c.casework_id,
  c.problem,
  u1.name CreatedByName,
  r2.response,
  r1.created,
  u2.name ReponseName
from casework c
left join user u1
  on c.user_id = u1.user_id
left join
(
  select max(created) created, casework_id
  from response r
  group by casework_id
) r1
  on c.casework_id = r1.casework_id
left join response r2
  on r1.created = r2.created
  and r1.casework_id = r2.casework_id
left join user u2
  on r2.user_id = u2.user_id
```

See [SQL Fiddle with demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/26ad9/1)

Comment: Hi, Is it possible to fetch Responce User Information also. Say, If responce table has user_id, then we can fetch name of user also, which has posted the responce ?

Comment: @shail if that data is in the `response` table, then you will return it during the second join.  In my example, the data would be available under the alias `r2`

Comment: Thanks for help.i means, can you show me the query for that also. RIght now, User table is assciated with Casework(The User who has created casework). I want to fetch user information of User who has posted responce also.(Assume user_id is a column in response table)

Comment: @shail do you have the `user_id` in the response table?

Comment: @shail please see my edit, you will join on the `user` table twice.  The first time will get you who created the casework, the second will get you who did the response.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your help. its a great hep to me. My small query is, if i want to fetch the oldest responce, should i use "min", instead of "max" in your query ?

Comment: @shail if you want the oldest, then use `min()`.  `max()` gets you the most recent entry.

Answer (score 1):

I have not tested it, but it might give you an idea

```
select c.casework_id, c.problem, 
(select name from user u where u.user_id = c.user_id ), 
(select r.reponse from response r where r.casework_id = c.casework_id ORDER BY r.created DESC LIMIT 1),
(select r.created from response r where r.casework_id = c.casework_id ORDER BY r.created DESC LIMIT 1),
from casework c
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT responce.casework_id, problem, name, responce, created 
FROM responce
JOIN
   (SELECT casework_id, problem, name 
    FROM casework JOIN user 
    ON casework.userid=user.userid) AS A
ON responce.casework_id=A.casework_id
ORDER BY responce, responce.casework_id
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
select c.caseword_id, c.problem, u.name,  response.response, responce.created from  asework c inner join user u on u.user_id = c.user_id left outer join select casework_id from response having max(created) group by casework_id) responsedata on responsedata.casework_id = c.casework_id
```